# How to add one array object to the another array object in javascript

Tags: javascript

my scenario is:

```
var a=[{name:"Rambabu",id:"101"},{name:"Divya",id:"102"}];

var b=[{name:"manu",id:"103"},{name:"sudha",id:"104"}];

var c= a array + b array data objects.
```

Expected output:

```
c= [{name:"Rambabu",id:"101"},{name:"Divya",id:"102"},{name:"manu",id:"103"},{name:"sudha",id:"104"}]
```

Comment: var c = a.concat(b);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.concat`

```js
var a=[{name:"Rambabu",id:"101"},{name:"Divya",id:"102"}];

var b=[{name:"manu",id:"103"},{name:"sudha",id:"104"}];

var c = a.concat(b);

console.log(c);
```

Or you can also use **spread operator...**

```js
var a=[{name:"Rambabu",id:"101"},{name:"Divya",id:"102"}];

var b=[{name:"manu",id:"103"},{name:"sudha",id:"104"}];

var c = [...a, ...b];

console.log(c);
```